# A função não retorna o valor mínimo?

Tags: python, funções, lista

Faça uma função Python chamada `min_max(t)`, que recebe uma lista de números, e retorna  outra lista contendo respectivamente o menor e o maior valor da lista original.

Segue o código até o momento:

```
def min_max(t):

    x = max(t)
    y = min(t)
    return  x,y
    
t = input("Digite sua lista: ")
print(min_max(t))
```

Mas, a função não está pegando o `min`, qual deve ser o problema?

Comment: `min_max = lambda t: [min(t),max(t)]`

Answer (score 11):

Na verdade o problema não está na sua função e sim em como a lista de números está sendo passada para ela:

```py
t = input("Digite sua lista: ")
print(min_max(t))
```

Isto está enviando uma *string* e não uma lista, portanto o seu código deveria conter uma conversão antes:

```py
def min_max(numeros): 
    return [max(numeros), min(numeros)]


if __name__ == "__main__":

    entrada = input("Digite sua lista: ")
    lista = [int(i) for i in entrada.split(",")]

    maior, menor = min_max(lista)

    print(maior, menor)
```

Claro, esta minha conversão não é perfeita já que não considera a existência de caracteres, números fracionados e outras coisas. Uma forma de deixá-la um pouco mais robusta seria usar o método `isnumeric()`:

```py
lista = [int(i) for i in entrada.split(",") if i.isnumeric()]
```

Mas neste caso apenas números inteiros maiores que zero seriam aceitos.

Answer (score 8):

O principal problema é que você está passando uma string como parâmetro da sua função:

```
t = input("Digite sua lista: ")
print(min_max(t))
```

O retorno da função `input` sempre é uma string. Quando você chama as funções `min` e `max` em uma string, você obterá os valores mínimos e máximos conforme a ordem alfabética:

```
min('spam') = 'a'
max('spam') = 's'
```

Como você precisa lidar com valores numéricos, você precisará tratar a sua entrada. Se está digitando os valores separados por um espaço em branco, precisará dividir a string nos espaços e converter cada valor para um número:

```
entrada = input("Digite sua lista: ")
numeros = [int(numero) for numero in entrada.split()]

print(min_max(numeros))
```

Assim, para uma entrada `3 6 1 5` a saída será `(6, 1)`, pois perceba que está retornando o maior e o menor número respectivamente.

Answer (score 7):

Como já foi dito o problema não está na função `min_max()` e sim na maneira como obtém sua entrada.

Se o objetivo do programa é que o usuário entre com uma lista python sintaticamente válida é possível utilizar a função [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) para analisar a entrada. Essa função avalia com segurança uma expressão ou uma string contendo um literal Python.

Para simplificar usarei uma [expressão lambda](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions).

```
import ast

min_max = lambda t: [min(t),max(t)]

try:
  t = ast.literal_eval(input("Digite sua lista: "))
except ValueError:
  t = [0];

print(min_max(t))
```

Exemplos:

```
Digite sua lista: 2,3,3,34
[2, 34]
Digite sua lista: [2,67,333, 0,-2324,8]
[-2324, 333]
```